# What's the command prompt's equivalent to cygwin's ctrl+z 

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

Whenever I want to quit something in Cygwin, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> usually does the trick.

What's the equivalent in the command prompt?

Comment: ^c (ctrl+c) i believe, but its been awhile and i am not 100% sure

Comment: it's not working, usually in cygwin when I do `git diff` ctrl+z would allow me to quickly exit a large diff, but in DOS `ctrl+z` and `ctrl+c` both do nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "quit something"; within **Windows `cmd`**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends the EOF character, which could terminate a process if you're providing input, but otherwise will probably do nothing.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *normally* sends SIGINT to the foreground process, which *should* terminate it, but programs can respond however they like - ie, they can catch the signal but then ignore it. The command can also be remapped to other jobs (such that for a specific program it doesn't really send a signal) or ignored entirely.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> always sends SIGBREAK, which again should terminate the process, but unlike Ctrl+C cannot be remapped, but can still be ignored. **This is probably what you need.**

Here's a source: [MSDN article: CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK Signals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682541%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, if you want to cancel a long DOS command (e.g. `C:\>dir /s`)

Comment: IIRC, Ctrl-C is only processed during I/O operations.  Would not interrupt a task that doesn't happen to enter a DOS I/O subroutine.

Comment: @Brian: yes, you're probably right. I think DMA57361's answer is correct - Ctrl-Break is probably what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Z is a DOS/Windows convention, not a Cygwin convention. Try the same keystroke.

Comment: As a honored member of Super User, please try to elaborate on your answer to provide [more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Mind filling this out a bit with exactly what it does?